# Problem: When Rigging pant with rigify pant move away

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

when rig the pants with rigify rig the pants move away from body. I am using automatic weight paint to rig the pant.[image: When i Apply automatic weight paint pant move away from body rigify rig]

Comment: hello, you probably need to correct this in Weight Paint mode

Comment: Well, You haven't set up Armature modifier for pants... You've set it up only for legs (according to your outliner).

Comment: Weight paint is working same.

Comment: I have applied the armature modifier to pant and weight painted it manually but it is giving me same results. i turned off the vertex group from armature modifier pant turned back to normal position but not animating with the rig.

Comment: Why did you apply it? After applying it transformation will be added to existing one

Comment: i applied it because the pant was deforming from its real pose to a different pose.

Answer (score 0):

Found way to fix the problem. First rig pant and then use sculpt tool on pant and adjust its position and it will work fine in pose mode but it will not work fine in edit mode.